# Transferring results from Zookeeper to webserver

Tags: apache, http, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

In my project I am calculating about 10-100mbs of data on a zookeeper worker. I then use HTTP PUT to transfer the data from the worker process to my webserver, which eventually gets delivered to the client. Is there anyway using Zookeeper or Curator to transfer that data or am I on my own to get the data out of the Worker process and onto a process outside my ensemble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend to use Zookeeper to transfer data, especially of such relatively large size. It is not really designed to do it. Zookeeper works best when it used to synchronize distributed processes or to store some relatively small configuration data that is shared among multiple hosts.

There is a [hard limit of 1 Mb per ZK node](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.5/api/org/apache/zookeeper/ZooKeeper.html#setData(java.lang.String,%20byte[],%20int)) and if you try to push it to the limit, Zookeeper clients may get timeouts and go into disconnected state while Zookeeper service processes large chunk of data.